# Explain analyze buffers - Does it give OS Cache as well

Tags: database, postgresql, caching

When we are doing `explain (analyze,buffers) the query` we get results and shows how much data comes from the cache and how much comes from disk.

But there are two layers in postgres, one is the OS cache and the shared buffers itself.Does the query plan shows the cache from shared_buffers or OS cache or both ?

There are extensions to see them individually i.e pgfincore and pg_buffer_cache, but what data I see in the query plan? Does it belong to shared_buffers/OS cache or both of them just combined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres only controls and knows about its own cache. It can't know about the cache management of the operating system.

> *Does it belong to shared_buffers/OS cache or both of them just combined?*

Those figures **only** relate to shared_buffers, not the cache of the operating system.